# hue installation error on AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rhel, hue

Hello I am trying to install Hue on AWS EC2 instance.

Following below link.

https://github.com/cloudera/hue

While doing step `make apps` I am getting below error.

```
[WARNING] Rule 1: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.RequireJavaVersion failed with message:
Detected JDK Version: 1.6.0-30 is not in the allowed range [1.7.0,1.7.1000].
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 14.717s
[INFO] Finished at: Sun Mar 09 13:18:59 EDT 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/25M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.0:enforce (default) on project hue-parent: Some Enforcer rules have failed. Look above for specific messages explaining why the rule failed. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I have java version

```
 java -version
java version "1.7.0_25"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.3.10.4.el6_4-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)
```

Additional information can be provided. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have another Java version in your system too. Based on what your installation says:

```
Detected JDK Version: 1.6.0-30
```

Make sure your `JAVA_HOME` variable points to the home of your Java 1.7 installation.

Answer (score 0):

You can also remove the JDK 7 check by editing:

> vim maven/pom.xml

And replacing the '7' by '6':

> ```
> <javaVersion>1.7</javaVersion>
> <sourceJavaVersion>1.7</sourceJavaVersion>
> <targetJavaVersion>1.7</targetJavaVersion>
> ```

(obviously you should it might be better to make sure Java 7 is the default if you plan to use 7)